# Creating Dynamically Sized DIV Boxes with Static Headers

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a type of dashboard that contains div's of various sizes.  The height and width are currently percentage based and the content of each div box is dynamic.  I need to create nice headers that describe the contents of the box.

The header is currently inside of the box.  This causes lots of problems when overflow is involved and makes spacing the inner content annoying.

Is there an easier way to get perfectly sized headers inside of the div or would it be easier to put them on top of the boxes like little hats.

This is extremely close to what I want but the header scrolls with the content!  That's really just terrible.

[Create div with title header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551945/create-div-with-title-header)

[image: Why is this so difficult?]

This is what I want, a widget like contraption that describes it's own contents.

Here's a Fiddle that getting quite close to what I would like

http://jsfiddle.net/exrXR/1019/

But Position Absolute completely overrides so many things...

Comment: And what's your mark-up? What're you working with? What have you tried?

Comment: try making a container div with header div and body div. you can set overflow to the body while keeping the header static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this demo together prior to the question being edited to include a link to a demo, so this is the first iteration, though after looking at the linked demo it seems the mark-up is fairly close:

```
<div class="dashWrap">
    <h2>header</h2>
    <div class="dashContent">
        <p><!-- content --></p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

The following CSS seems to do as you require:

```
.dashWrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}
.dashWrap h2 {
    background-color: #ffa;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
}

.dashWrap .dashContent {
    max-height: 5em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NyXqu/).

---

**Edited** following question from OP (in comments):

> ...I have no clue why it works. If you would be so kind as to give me a brief explanation as to why the header stays in place so miraculously that would be extremely helpful.

The reason that the `h2` stays 'in place' is, simply, because I've not moved it, or changed its default `display` behaviour (an `h2` defaults to `display: block`); which means it remains in its place within the document's flow.

Its sibling, the `.dashContent`, element is able to scroll because it has two rules, the first is `max-height` which prevents the element growing vertically to accommodate its descendant element(s) and the second is `overflow-y` (which in some browsers requires that `overflow-x` is also set, hence the above), which allows the contents of `.dashContent` to scroll.

Comment: This is very much what I'm looking for.  But I have no clue why it works.  If you would be so kind as to give me a brief explanation as to why the header stays in place so miraculously that would be extremely helpful.  Copy/Pasting SO code isn't going to make me a better programmer.

Comment: I've *tried* to offer a brief explanation; but I'm not sure where it is that you're stuck. Kudos for striving to understand, though! And, of course, if you have further questions then please feel free to ask, and I'll do my best. =)

Comment: It took me two reads but that covers it.  It's so simple that it just didn't make sense to me.  CSS is the bane of my existance.  Thank you for assisting in my never ending battle with style sheets.